# onNavigationStateChange is rendering twice in react native WebView component

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-realtime-database, webview

I am using a Webview for the payment and after the payment, the data is being stored to the firebase. The firebase part code is in onNavigationStateChange function but somehow the data is getting stored twice in the firebase. Whatsoever is in this function, everything is getting called twice. I am unable to figure out why this is happening??

```
 <WebView
     ref="webview"
     source={{ uri: this.state.result }}
     onNavigationStateChange={this.onNavigationChange.bind(this)}
 />
```

***onNavigationStateChange***

```
onNavigationChange(webViewState) {
        let hitUrl = webViewState.url;
        if (hitUrl.includes('payment_id=')) {
            let payment_final_id = hitUrl.split("payment_id=").pop().split("&")[0]
            this.props.emptyCart(this.props.cartItems.cart)
            this.orderToDb(this.state.cartItems,this.state.uid,payment_final_id,new Date().toLocaleString().split(",")[0],this.state.address)
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you solve it?

Comment: Yup solved it....

Comment: i have the same problem, how can i solve it?

Comment: console.log the webview state. Actually hitUrl.includes('payment_id=') was getting rendered twice so I just change this condition by seeing what is rendering once only.